# Table with 100 rows; need to show a div dependent on a link clicked in the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The table has over hundred rows. I have already have a link that looks like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:teamviewerconnect('78978978')"><img src="http://internaleservername:2323/img/remote_small.png" alt="remote connection icon" border="0"></a>
```

What I would like to do is have a DIV open in the middle of the screen on top of everything displaying data that is in a variable that I have per row. I could create a div per row that is hidden but all the solutions I have found to show/hide a div on a click are reliant on the div id being unique. I am not sure if this is possible but the link above can't change but can we get it to display automatically when that link is clicked without having to click another show/hide?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you could add some code into the teamviewerconnect function, then use $(this) supposing you have one of these links per row.

Comment: What table would we be talking about here?  There are quite a few tables in this world.

Comment: The table I am using is a list of servers with various information about each server. The teamviewer connect function facilitates a one click connection to the server. When you suggest using $(this) can you give me an example? I am fine with CSS/HTML/PHP/ASP but I am terrible with Javascript. The table is created in a looping Do Until RecordSet End and one line of the table is written per iteration.

Comment: It's not really clear what you expect. Are you trying to create a div which contains and displays data for that row, which data you are getting from the server in an AJAX call? It's not hard to create popups by handling the `onclick` event of the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to do the display of the div it sounds to me like you would be well-served with a [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (or whatever JS framework you prefer). Other users have answered with was to display the div without jQuery.  You can easily center this on the page.

Then you'll want to add an onClick event handler to each link, using code like @Gaby has posted (which uses jQuery)

Inside the event handler function, as @Treemonkey pointed out, you can grab your extra data by pulling it out of `$(this)`

```
$('a[href|="teamviewerconnect"]').click(function(){
   //Get whatever data you need like
   var idNumber = $(this).attr('href').split("'")[1];
   //Use that data to update the HTML of your div if needed, or do an ajax query here
   $('#mydialogdivid').html('<p>Blah Blah Blah ' + idNumber);
   $('#mydialogdivid').dialog();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

make the div `position:absolute`, and than you'll need to do something along the line:

```
   $("a").click(function(e){
      $('div').css("left", e.pageX +'px');
      $('div').css("top", e.pageY +'px')
   });
```

But to get the wanted information, you'll prolly need an AJAX call, or atleast some sort of append to html.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension but more for your answer (YOU DO NOT NEED AJAX)

This can then go inside your $(document).ready(function(){
E.G

```
function openDiv(txt1, txt2, txt3){
  $("#divID").html("<div>"+txt1+"</div><div>"+txt2+"</div><div>"+txt3+"</div>");
  $('#divID').css({"left": e.pageX +'px', "top": e.pageY +'px', 'display':'block'});
}
```

then on each TableRow (gessing its serverside loop) on the loop add the `onclick="openDiv('data1','data2','data3')"`

for more information you can just add more to the list of txt1, txt2,... and then add "+txt3+" again with what you want

Im using txt1/2 as example you can make the name more meaning full, and if you want to make it so there is static text just add it before the "+ of each var your using

Answer (score 0):

You can target those links with

```
$('a[href*="teamviewerconnect"]').click(function(){
   // show/hide here
});
```

to make the div stay centered and on top of everything try

```
<div class="view-data"></div>
```

and

```
.view-data{
  position:fixed;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-150px; /*half of height*/
  margin-left:-150px; /*half of width*/
}
```